# how to work around error in deployment with appcfg

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, appcfg

Since some days I am getting repeatly the error

```
WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given)
```

for the command

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 -V v4-1-2 update frontends_live.yaml
```

I can see Google is working on it but no solution for me

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11928

Any work around to deploy?

EDIT: Deployment is not going through and if i go to https://appengine.google.com/deployment I see no default version selected afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`appcfg.py rollback .` will help you

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9807